# How to add a anko widget into another anko widget?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

Like the following, how to add `customDialog` to that alert?

```
   val customDialog = UI {
        verticalLayout{
            padding = dip(16)

            val shortName = editText {
                hint = "Short name"
                textSize = 24f
            }

            val pwd = editText {
                hint = "Password"
                textSize = 24f
            }
        }
    }

    alert("Let me join in") {
        customView {
            verticalLayout {
                customDialog

                yesButton {
                    isCancelable = true
                }

                noButton { it.dismiss() }
            }
        }

    }.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

By using extension functions.

```
fun Context.customDialog() = verticalLayout {
    padding = dip(16)

    val shortName = editText {
        hint = "Short name"
        textSize = 24f
    }

    val pwd = editText {
        hint = "Password"
        textSize = 24f
    }
}

alert("Let me join in") {
    customView {
        verticalLayout {
            customDialog()

            yesButton {
                isCancelable = true
            }

            noButton { it.dismiss() }
        }
    }

}.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tried but nothing shows in the alert. :(